# Fragment container layout overlapping main activity contents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout, android-framelayout

I am trying to add a custom header in my main activity that already contains a bottom navigator and a `framelayout` that acts as a container for the `fragments` i want to display.

The below given code contains a `Linearlayout["@+id/application_header]` that should act as the application header, however the header is displayed by the `fragment` `container[@+id/main_container]` is overlapping the header.

Tried the properties  `android:layout_below` and  `android:layout_above` but it is still overlapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.amplitude.tron.volksradio.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/application_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RADIO"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/application_header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_navigation"
        android:background="#50b1b5b9">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it my self, although there might other clean solution and would be accepted as answer if found feasible.

I just added `android:layout_marginTop="50dp"` which is same as the height of element with id - `@+id/application_header`

PS- i don't know if this would effect screens with different sizes and my testing device is only 5.5 inches to which the solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/application_header"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal">

     <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="RADIO"
          android:layout_gravity="center"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/main_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/application_header"
          android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
     </FrameLayout>

     <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          design:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_navigation"
          android:background="#50b1b5b9">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` work with `RelativeLayout`. BTW, the `LinearLayout` with only one `TextView` is redundant. You can just use `TextView`. Here are some options on how to get that done.

**Using** `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/application_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="RADIO"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/application_header">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#50b1b5b9"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Using** `LinearLayout`:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/application_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="RADIO"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#50b1b5b9"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

One more (better) alternative would be **using** [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) with [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/application_header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_navigation"
        android:background="#50b1b5b9"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, there is already a relative layout in the code but i dint add it sorry for that, tried your second solution it just pushed the navigation menu outside of the screen. Last solution is not what i am looking for because my title is custom made

Comment: For the `Toolbar` solution, you can still use custom views. From the [references](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html): "a toolbar may contain a combination of the following optional elements: One or more custom views. The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured."

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the layout align center of the screen by adding this :

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

also add a padding or margin incase there is any small amount of overlapping